# empty json when I encode an array with few dozen of objects from server

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

### I have some problems with communication from server to my android app. When I send a json in which there is an array with few dozen of data, something goes wrong.

This is what the server returns when there aren't record that satisfies my conditions:
It is displayed with `Log.e(TAG, json.toString());`
`{"comuni":[]}`

This is what the server returns when the sql statement found some raws.
It is displayed with `Log.e(TAG, json.toString());`

```
    {"comuni": [
        {
            "codCatastale": "D546",
            "nomeComune": "Pianopoli",
            "cap": "88040",
            "codProvincia": "CZ"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G541",
            "nomeComune": "Piana di Monte Verna",
            "cap": "81013",
            "codProvincia": "CE"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G542",
            "nomeComune": "Piana Crixia",
            "cap": "17058",
            "codProvincia": "SV"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G543",
            "nomeComune": "Piana degli Albanesi",
            "cap": "90037",
            "codProvincia": "PA"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G546",
            "nomeComune": "Pian Camuno",
            "cap": "25050",
            "codProvincia": "BS"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G547",
            "nomeComune": "Piancastagnaio",
            "cap": "53025",
            "codProvincia": "SI"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G549",
            "nomeComune": "Piancogno",
            "cap": "25052",
            "codProvincia": "BS"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G551",
            "nomeComune": "Piandimeleto",
            "cap": "61026",
            "codProvincia": "PU"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G552",
            "nomeComune": "Pian di Sco",
            "cap": "52026",
            "codProvincia": "AR"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G553",
            "nomeComune": "Piane Crati",
            "cap": "87050",
            "codProvincia": "CS"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G555",
            "nomeComune": "Pianella",
            "cap": "65019",
            "codProvincia": "PE"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G556",
            "nomeComune": "Pianello del Lario",
            "cap": "22010",
            "codProvincia": "CO"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G557",
            "nomeComune": "Pianello Val Tidone",
            "cap": "29010",
            "codProvincia": "PC"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G558",
            "nomeComune": "Pianengo",
            "cap": "26010",
            "codProvincia": "CR"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G559",
            "nomeComune": "Pianezza",
            "cap": "10044",
            "codProvincia": "TO"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G560",
            "nomeComune": "Pianezze",
            "cap": "36060",
            "codProvincia": "VI"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G561",
            "nomeComune": "Pianfei",
            "cap": "12080",
            "codProvincia": "CN"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G564",
            "nomeComune": "Pianico",
            "cap": "24060",
            "codProvincia": "BG"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G565",
            "nomeComune": "Pianiga",
            "cap": "30030",
            "codProvincia": "VE"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G568",
            "nomeComune": "Piano di Sorrento",
            "cap": "80063",
            "codProvincia": "NA"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G570",
            "nomeComune": "Pianoro",
            "cap": "40065",
            "codProvincia": "BO"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G571",
            "nomeComune": "Piansano",
            "cap": "1010",
            "codProvincia": "VT"
        },
        {
            "codCatastale": "G572",
            "nomeComune": "Piantedo",
            "cap": "23010",
            "codProvincia": "SO"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is what it returns when the raws that are found are more then some dozen. With 80 records already gives this error.
It is displayed with `Log.e(TAG, "Malformed Json string: " + json.toString() + e.getMessage());`

> 06-18 19:02:07.012 13689-13689/com.example.alberto.easyfood
>   E/CommunicationManager: Could not parse malformed JSON: End of input
>   at character 0 of  json string:

Like you can see the json string is empty.

### This is my php code:

```
<?php

/*** Opening the connection with the db ***/
include 'open_db_connection.php';

define('RESIDENCES', 'comuni');

try {
  /*** Getting data ***/
  $json = file_get_contents("php://input");
  /*** Decoding json ***/
  $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
  $residence = $data[ATTR_RESIDENCE_NAME];
  if($residence != ""){
    print(json_encode((getResidences($residence))));
  }else return null;

} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;



/**
 * Function that return an array of arrays containing information about residences begginning with the same initials letters that are passed at this functon.
 * For each residence there will be also the other information like the province id.
 * Parameters:
 *  Residence (it can be the full name or only the initials letters)
 */
function getResidences($residence){
  global $conn;
  /*** Preparing the SQL statement ***/
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.TABLE_RESIDENCES.' WHERE '.ATTR_RESIDENCE_NAME.' LIKE :residence');
  /*** Binding parameters ***/
  $param = "$residence%";
  $stmt->bindParam(':residence', $param);
  /*** exceute the query ***/
  $stmt->execute(); 

  /*** Setting the type of array (in this case it will be an associative array)***/
  $residences[RESIDENCES] = $stmt->FetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  return $residences;
}

?>
```

### This is my java code

### Here there is the method that passes the Url of my php page and a JSONObject to be sent

```
public String[] getResidences(String residence_initials, Context context){
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    if(!residence_initials.isEmpty()){
        try {
            json.put(DB_RESIDENCE, residence_initials);
            json = CommunicationManager.postData(URL_RESIDENCES, json);
            if(json != null){
                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(RESIDENCES);
                Log.e(TAG, json.toString());
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Malformed Json string: " + json.toString() + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

### And this is the static method that send my json to the server and returns a JSONObject that might be the response

```
private static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 8000;
private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
private static final String POST_METHOD = "POST";
public static JSONObject postData(String url, JSONObject dataToBeSent){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    if(dataToBeSent != null) {
        URL serverURL = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            serverURL = new URL(url);
            /* Opening a connection */
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverURL.openConnection();
             /* Setting timeout */
             connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
             connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
             /* Using the POST method sending data */
             connection.setRequestMethod(POST_METHOD);
             connection.setDoInput(true);
             connection.setDoOutput(true);
             DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
             outputStream.writeBytes(dataToBeSent.toString());
             outputStream.flush();
             outputStream.close();
             connection.connect();

             /* Getting the response */
             int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
             if(responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                 /* If the response is a 200 http response it will get the message the server sent */
                 String line;
                 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                 while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                     stringBuilder.append(line + '\n');
                 }

                 jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
             }

             connection.disconnect();
         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
         } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             Log.e(TAG, "Could not parse malformed JSON: " + e.getMessage() + "\njson string: "+ stringBuilder);
         }

     }
     /* Return a JSON Object*/
     return jsonObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have doubt on this line -

```
JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(RESIDENCES);
```

Check the value of `RESIDENCES` it must be `comuni`.

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Yes, its value is `comuni`.
I think the prolem is about the length of the json or something else bound to the json

Comment: I didn't get, why you are returning null only in function getResidences.

Comment: It should return an array with my residences, but at the moment I'm testing if it works correctly. So now I'm displaying them with the method `Log.e(...)`. As soon as it works I will be able to return the array.
It's only temporary.

Comment: In log.e you are displaying the response data not the array, 
JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(RESIDENCES);
Log.e(TAG, json.toString());
Can you please tell me what is the log being printed here?

Comment: I know, but the JSONArray is get from the json so it should display also the array contents.
Anyway, `Log.e(TAG, json.toString());` displays the String that I posted in my answer.